# JVM error when debugging xslt with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to debug an xslt 2.0 with Eclipse which worked fine previously. Now I guess I messed things up with a new Eclipse or java version because when I right click on my xslt and choose *'Debug as xslt transformation'*, after confirming *'the JRE instance default XSLT processor does not support debugging. Would you like to debug using the default Xalan 2.71 processor instead?'*

I get an error dialog:

**Error: could not create the java virtual machine.
Error: a fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.
Cannot connect to VM
com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException**

In the console it shows:
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Users\Michael\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

I've tried reinstalling Eclipse & reinstalling Java .
Setting my system variable  JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin.   (Environment variable is: %JAVA_HOME%\bin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. You'll need to [report it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&component=wst.xsl). Setting the default version of Java on your machine to Java 8 or older might work around it.

Comment: I've removed the 11.0 JDK and reinstalled 8.0, changed the java_home variable and my eclipse.ini: 
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\server

Glad I got it back to work, thnx!